# getting value of JSON-name

Tags: javascript, json

I need to get the name of a JSON element as a value in Javascript.

My Json looks like that:

```
{

"1": {
    "state": {
        "on": true,
        "bri": 144,
       [...]
    }
}
```

I need to get the "1" as a value, as it is the ID of a device and can change.

I tried several things, but

```
var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(requestId.responseText);
        console.log(jsonResponse);
```

gets me the whole Json object. And

```
var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(requestId.responseText);
        console.log(jsonResponse[i]);
```

get an undefined.

Some advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to iterate the object in order to access unknown keys

```
for( var key in jsonResponse){
   console.log(key)
}
// OR    
Object.keys(jsonResponse).forEach(key =>{
   console.log(key)
})
```

If you know there is only one key can do:

```
var key =  Object.keys(jsonResponse)[0],
    state = jsonResponse[key].state;
console.log(state.bri);
```